# matching comma separated string to ids mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

1. Users
2. Locations

now 90% of the time 1 user is connected to 1 location. But now a scenario has come up where 1 user has 2 locations

I have done this

```
Locations table
id     name
1      A
2      B
3      C
```

users table

```
id     location_id
1      1
2      1
3      1,2
```

now i want to do a query where i can match a comma separated string like 1,2 to the table locations an get 1 and 2.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what is the problem? How to query for `1,2` or how to turn `1,2` into `1` and `2` when you get `1,2` as a result from the query?

Comment: i want to give a string like 1,2 and then get id 1 and id 2 back from locations table

Comment: but this all need to be variable so where location id = 1 and location id = 2 will not suit.

Comment: Normalize, make a `user_locations` table. Delimited data in one column is at best a performance bottleneck, but more often an extreme handicap. However, for now, a `JOIN locations ON FIND_IN_SET(locations.id,user.location_id) != 0`

Comment: Chances are it will be better to use another table to represent this many-to-many relationship; eliminate the location_id field from users, add another table, say user_locations, with fields user_id, location_id and put TWO rows for user 3, one with (3,1) and another with (3,2). That is how SQL is supposed to work :)

Comment: @Wrikken I hear u.. and I realize that (now) also. But the problem is 90% of the time this does not appear so a comma seperated solution seemed like a good choise. But maybe a reorganisation of tables is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad choice of data format.  You are storing lists of things in a string, when SQL has a great structure for storing lists.  It is called a table, and specifically a junction table in this case.  Plus, you are storing (presumably) numeric ids as strings.

None the less, you can do what you want:

```
select u.*, l.name
from users u join
     locations l
     on find_in_set(l.id, u.location_id) > 0;
```

Performance will not be good, but that is part of the price of having a poor data layout.

Comment: I think you're right about the bad choise, so im thinking to add a junction table. But your awnser worked also.. so ill mark this as the right awnser

Answer (score 1):

If you have the power to change your schema slightly, the best thing to do would be to normalize your tables by creating a separate table mapping users to locations.  That way it becomes:

```
Locations
ID     name
1       A
2       B
...

Users
ID      name (or whatever)
1       jsmith
2       jdoe

UsersLocations
ID     user_id        location_id
1       1                  1
1       2                  1
1       2                  2
```

Comment: I agree, but why the pseudo-ID? `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, location_id)` would work just as well.

Comment: Yeah. That's true.  I always tend to create them just in case I want to add to the relationship later.

Comment: Hm, so you mean that a `user_id, location_id`  will no longer be unique at that point? 'cause otherwise, adding columns can still happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM users u JOIN locations l ON FIND_IN_SET(l.id, u.location_id) > 0
```